# Git hook creation - You are on a branch yet to be born

Tags: git, git-checkout

So im setting up a git and following this guide http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto.

I get as far as this command:

```
# GIT_WORK_TREE=/home3/trncprop/public_html/tpcapp git checkout -f
```

And get the following error message

```
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! Littleswany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is supposed to be in a hook, not to be executed directly in `website.git`

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

That means you need to create a website.git/hooks/post-receive file, with that command in it, and make it executable.

That will allow you to push commits top that bare repo (website.git), which will trigger the post-receive hook, and will checkout the repo content into a different working tree.

Comment: I have tried that, for this bit "GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f" after the = what address should i put?

Comment: @littleswany you should put any path you want your website content to be checked out (in this example `/var/www/www.example.org`), which in turn would be referenced by your http server `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: @littleswany this is the folder in which your website is checked out. But you still need to set up an web server which will let you use a "web address" (an url) translated internally into this folder (the DocumentRoot).

Comment: @littleswany see an example of said web server and `DocumentRoot` setting in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access