# using git to sync two identical repos one on local and other on remote host(not github)

Tags: git

I have git installed on localhost as well as remote host with the same project folder. 
So 1 repo on localhost and 1 on remote host both containing same files. What I want to do is use localhost files for development and then push them in the remote to update there as well.

How to go about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a remote to your local repo, and push to your remote host.

```
git remote add origin /url/remotehost/bare_repo
git push --all
```

For that, your remote host must have a way to be accessed by your local host through one of the **[supported protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)**:

- git daemon
- shared folder
- http(s)
- ssh

And your remote host must have a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)**, in order to be able to push to it.

On that bare repo, you can declare a [post-receive hook which will checkout the received content in your remote host project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25583200/6309).

---

The OP chose ssh (`ssh://202.XXX.xx.xx:/path/to/repo.git`), but had issue fetching/pushing.

> cloning the remote repo is also not working its giving me error

```
 Bad port '' fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I advised to specify the user which owns the repo on the remote server.
For instance '`git`': `git@202.XXX.xx.xx`.
Then to try with and without the '`:`':

```
git@202.XXX.xx.xx:/path/to/repo.git 
# or 
git@202.XXX.xx.xx/path/to/repo.git
```

The sshd must be running. The port should be the default one (22).
One can check the [sshd logs on the server side (`/var/auth/log`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114189/where-are-my-sshd-logs).

After all that, the Op reports the setup is working.

---

The `post-receive` hook must be put in the bare repo on the server, and be made executable:

```
cat > /path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/live/folder GIT_DIR=/path/to/bare/repo.git git checkout -f


chmod +x /path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive
```