# Deploy a Symfony website with Git on OVH shared server

Tags: git, symfony, ovh

I want to configure an automatic deployment of my Symfony website directly from git to my ovh server (Performance offer - with SSH access).

I followed these ovh instructions : https://docs.ovh.com/fr/fr/web/hosting/24-days/day07/

1. installed composer in $HOME/bin
2. created a distant git repository $HOME/depot_git_beta with git init --bare
3. created a post-receive file at $HOME/depot_git_beta/hooks

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Hook post-receive

   # Force source bash profile to update PATH
   source ~/.bash_profile
   source ~/.bashrc

   GIT_REPO=$HOME/depot_git_beta
   DEPLOY_DIR=$HOME/beta

   # Go to deploy directory to load ovhconfig
   cd $DEPLOY_DIR
   ovhConfig
   cd -

   while read prevsha1 newsha1 ref
   do
       if [[ $ref =~ .*/develop$ ]];
       then
           echo "Deploying develop branch to beta..."
           git --work-tree=$DEPLOY_DIR --git-dir=$GIT_REPO checkout -f
           cd $DEPLOY_DIR

           # Install vendors
           composer install --no-dev --no-interaction
           echo "Vendors updated!"

           # Update database
           php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
           echo "Database for beta environment updated!"

           # Clear cache
           php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
           php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
           echo "Cache cleared!"

       else
           echo "Ref: $ref isn't develop. Nothing to do on beta"
       fi
   done
   ```
4. add the distant repository

   ```
   git remote add ovh VOTRE_IDENTIFIANT@ftp.clusterXXX.hosting.ovh.net:depot_git_beta
   ```
5. but when I do `git push ovh develop` it does seems to work, git bash tells it's up to date, but nothing seems to have happened in ovh server.

Any idea what went wrong or where I should look first ?

Comment: If git tells its up to date, then any server side hooks won't be executed, can you add a new commit, and push that? Any output of your git hook should show up at the client side when you push

Comment: Use `git commit --allow-empty -m 'push to execute post-receive'` to trigger the post-receive hook. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703197/6162120

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Nothing is working unfortunately. To be clear, here is what I did : 1/ tap in git bash : `$ git push ovh develop`
and it executed this:
`Counting objects: 15254, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11927/11927), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15254/15254), 66.97 MiB | 631.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 15254 (delta 6552), reused 10256 (delta 2703)
To ftp.clusterXXX.hosting.ovh.net:depot_git_beta
 * [new branch]      develop -> develop`

Comment: And 2/ I did the `git commit --allow-empty -m 'push to execute post-receive'` and nothing is happening, not even the folder is created

Comment: Are you sure that `$HOME/depot_git_beta/hooks/post-receive` is executable?

Comment: yes : -rwxr-xr-x+

Comment: Replace the first line by `#!/bin/bash -x` to turn on echo. And make sure the directory DEPLOY_DIR exists on the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153341/discussion-between-piarston-and-melody).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was essentially that as I was not deploying the master branch, I had to precise it in this line:

`$ git --work-tree=... --git-dir=... checkout -f develop`

See this [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150229/5633813)!

(And thank you piarson for helping me to find the solution!)